# Teaching K-8 math in the style of "A Mathematician’s Lament"

Tags: reference-request, primary-education, mathematical-pedagogy, curriculum

Here's a link to the full paper, colloquially known as [Lockhart](http://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=37815)'s Lament:

**Link:** https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf

In the context of K-8 learning materials that take into account the concerns discussed in Paul Lockhart's essay **A Mathematician's Lament**, I wonder if anyone knows of syllabi, curricula, or worksheets that I can use to supplement my child's "Core" program in school, and what experiences (if any) others have with using said materials.

Comment: If you want to supplement your child's program, let her play games. The type of learning described there is an exploratory process, and rather than trying to re-teach your child his school curriculum "in a different way", just play games and do puzzles with him. Tangram, Go/gomuku, connect-four, 2048. But don't _teach_ her how to play. Let her discover the tricks herself.

Comment: @WillieWong any thoughts on the Dover Tangram book?

Comment: On that I cannot give you better advice than random reviewers on Amazon.com. Also, there are at least two different Tangram books published by Dover. If you allow your little one to use a tablet or a smartphone, there are also several free Tangram apps, FWIW.

Answer (score 13):

In *A Mathematician's Lament*, Paul Lockhart describes what is wrong with math education in schools. To get a good idea of how he would do things differently, you should read his book titled *[Measurement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674057554)*. The ideas in it are for slightly older students, but the approach is what you're looking for.

I recommend that you try to work through *Measurement* yourself, and see what questions pop up for you that you can share with your child. If you are comfortable with math yourself, you might want to start a math circle. If you are not that comfortable, and you live close to one, check out a [Julia Robinson Mathematics Festival](http://juliarobinsonmathfestival.org/).

You might also find my book, *[Playing with Math: Stories from Math Circles, Homeschoolers, and Passionate Teachers](http://www.moebiusnoodles.com/playingwithmath/)*, useful. It should be out in November.